# Custom PHP login form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, authentication

Is it possible to create a PHP login form without those fill-in boxes?

See this: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/rpc-demo.html

The code can include JavaScript. It should look like a Linux terminal:

```
username: {the user writes his username then presses enter; the following line appears:}
username@password: {the user writes the password ...}
```

Comment: You could do it using Javascript.

Comment: Why?  What benefit does it have other than looking interesting?  Web uses expect web interfaces.  Something like this is almost certainly going to break form autofill and tools like LastPass.  Your users will not thank you for it.

Comment: Check this out: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/rpc-demo.html

Comment: Why? What benefit does it have other than looking interesting? -- none

Comment: Yes, Turcia, that is what I want :)

Comment: @GordonM, I don't see why we need to know WHY he/she wants to do it, I feel we should just help him out in doing it. Many notorious things of our age may have looked stupid in the past, but now they are important.
Abbey: I think you are getting down voted for not asking a proper question. See Help Section to understand better, than edit your question to make it fit the SO rules. Anyways I think  you could use JS and PHP and surely can achieve it, have a look around the web or improve your question.

Comment: Agree with Mr.Web. Sometimes Abbey's client wants it

Comment: Your question is still too broad to be answered without giving you a full PHP/JS lesson. Please review the terms and tell us what your current code is, what you have tried so far, etc...

Comment: @Mr.Web My concern isn't whether or not it looks good, my concern is over usability issues.  Tools like form autofill and LastPass won't work well with a solution that isn't a standard text and password field.

Comment: It is bad practice to downvote any questiong that you don't like (which easily could block user from the forum). She is trying to create something which is non-standard. This question seems very interesting and inspiring to me.

Comment: @DamanDaman That's your opinion, mine is that it doesn't meet the minimum standards for a StackOverflow question, namely that it's about a specific issue and not asking how to do something in general terms.  Standards on this site have been slipping badly and they need to be addressed.

Comment: @GordonM ok, I see what you mean and you should of course explain the person all of the risks he/she's going into. But I feel I someone wants to do a cake with mayonnaise, I wouldn't ask why, I would tell him "Ok, listen nobody will want to eat that, but this is how you can do it: ....".

Comment: @DamanDaman this question is not a proper question as per the Help Section in SO therefore is correct to down vote it.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the question? She had an issue and looking for solution.

Comment: @Abbey: please be advised that it is a _horrible_, outright ***dangerous*** idea to grant shell access via this method. Basically you lever out any security measures of which the vast majority aimed at remote logins and tend to have a `localhost` exception. This allows brute force attacks to be commenced, which wouldn't even be logged in most default OS configurations. To grant access, you should always use ssh, and only if absolutely necessary and only in a system hardened by a security specialist.

Comment: @Markus Thanks for advice. Wouldn't forced delays solve brute force attacks?

Comment: @Abbey: in short, no, not at all. You need to have _a lot_ of security measures like brute force blockers, host and network based intrusion detection systems and whatnot. I would strongly advise against pursuing this unless you either really know what you are doing or get into touch with an experienced security specialist.

Comment: @Markus Ok. I will look for some documentation.

Comment: @Abbey: knowledge != experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate linux terminal with the styled `textarea` HTML element. There is a [jQuery library](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/) that will help you to do that.

Your login 'form' will look like this:
[image]

Then, you can check and proceed user input on the server side.

Comment: He'll still need Javascript to change the password prompt to display the username.

Comment: PHP + javascript is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a code here: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/examples.php#json_rpc_demo

 Demo is here: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/rpc-demo.html

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helps you to find it.